# joining two tables in my sql desn't return a result set

Tags: mysql, sql, join

Hi I have run in to a problem when retrieving a particular data set using 3 tables in a MySql database.Tables are as follows

```
Student
SID | Name | Age | Telephone

Term
TID | Start | End

Payment
PID | TID | SID | Value
```

SID is primary key of Student table. TID is primary key of Term table. PID is primary key of Payment table. TID and SID in Payment table are foreign key references.

Student table contains data of students. Term table contain data of term start and end dates. Payment table contain data about student payment. Records in Payment table may either contain TID or not. When it is a registration payment there will be no TID. Otherwise it is a term fee and there will be TID. What I want is a list of students that hasn't paid this terms fees until today. Asuume this TID is in a variable. How can I obtain the list of students ? IT SEEMS SUPER EASY. BUT I COULDNT FIND AN ANSWER THIS WHOLE DAY

Comment: Think `JOIN` and `WHERE`

Comment: please show an example of your expected outcome rather than explaining it

Comment: Read :"Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: please don't use all-caps, it's considered as shouting and potentially aggressive. There's never any need to shout. Anyway, please show us some sample data, your desired output, and the code for how you tried to do this already, then we can understand your problem more accurately. Essentially you just want a list of all students whose ID is _not in_ a list of all payments which relate to the selected term

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0):

You want a list of just those students who do not have a TID-populated record whose start and end dates are either side of today, in Payment

```
SELECT * FROM
  student
  LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (select * from payment where TID is not null and NOW() BETWEEN start and end) this_term_payments
  on student.id = this_term_payments.sid
WHERE
  this_term_payments.ID is null
```

There are many ways to skin this cat. Here is one. We filter the payments table down to just a list of this term's payments (that's the inner query). And left join that to students. Left join means we get all students, matched with this_term_payments if the this_term_payments row exists, or NULL in every this_term_payments column if the term payment doesn't exist. The where clause then filters the whole results set down to "just those who don't have a term payment" by looking for those nulls that the left join creates

FWIW, your question attracted close votes because it didn't include example data/demonstrate the level of your effort we like to see on SQL questions. If you'd included sample data for all your tables and an example result set you wanted to see out, it means we can write an exact query that meets your requirements.

This is a bit of a double edged sword for me; we can deliver exactly what you ask for even if you later realise it's not what you want (asking in English is far more vague than giving an example result set) but at the same time we basically become some free outsourced homework contractor or similar, doing your work for you and removing learning opportunities along the way. Hopefully you'll take this query (it's likely it doesn't output everything you want, or outputs stuff you don't want) and craft what you want out of it now that the technique has been explained.. :)

For an SQL question that was relatively well received (by the time i'd finished editing it following up on the comments), and attracted some great answers take a look here:

[Fill in gaps in data, using a value proportional to the gap distance to data from the surrounding rows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52387566/fill-in-gaps-in-data-using-a-value-proportional-to-the-gap-distance-to-data-fro)

That's more how you need to be asking SQL questions - say what you want, give example data, give scripts to help people create your same data so they can have a play with their idea without the boring bits of creating the data first. I picked on that one because I didn't even have any SQL attempts to show at the time; it was just a thought exercise. Having nothing working isn't necessarily a barrier to asking a good question

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
   select s.name, p.value from Student s, Term t, Payment p where t.TID = p.TID and s.SID=p.SID and p.TID is null;
```